# Python Anaconda connect to Oracle 32 bits

Tags: python, oracle, anaconda

I'm wondering how to connect to Oracle 32 bits via Python (Anaconda). Is it possible or I need to have Oracle 64 bits ? I'm a beginner on Python, thank you for your indulgence :)
My code is :

```
import pyodbc
connectString = 
'Driver={Oracle dans  OraClient12Home1};
Server=xx_xx_xx.server.lan:1521/xx_xx_xx.xx_xx_xx.server.l 
an;uid=xx;pwd=xx'
#connectString = 'Driver={Microdsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=<host>: 
<port>/<db>.<host>;uid= <username>;'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectString)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT DAVANCE.CD FROM DAVANCE")
for row in cursor.fetchall() :
print(row)
```

The error is :
InterfaceError: ('IM003', "[IM003] Le pilote spécifié n'a pas été chargé en raison de l'erreur système  1114: Une routine d’initialisation d’une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué. (Oracle dans OraClient12Home1, C:\Progra~1\ORA12\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN\SQORA32.DLL). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: Please [edit] the question with details of what you are having problems with.

Comment: Oracle supports interoperability between different "client" libraries and the database in lots of scenarios e.g. between 32-bit & 64-bit, big & little endian architectures, and between different versions of the libraries and the DB.  Make sure you are using the correct architecture of Oracle libraries as required by your python. Check your PATH environment variable.  Google shows a few hits, e.g https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4495059/system-error-1114-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-failed